# WinForms Label Right-To-Left Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Label inside a GroupBox. The RightToLeft property of Form, GroupBox and Label are Yes. The Auto-Size property of the Label is True. The Text of the Label is set at run-time. The problem is that the label grows from left to right instead of right to left. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label grow from right to left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612148/label-grow-from-right-to-left)

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate with this:
[Label grow from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612148/label-grow-from-right-to-left)

Basically Auto-Size property needs to be false.

Comment: If I set the Auto-Size to false then do I have to set Width for the label?

Comment: You can do a pre-measurement of the label size. Please see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388937/determine-label-size-based-upon-amount-of-text-and-font-size-in-winforms-c